# How do I access nested values in a multi-dimensional array with non-numeric indexes

Tags: php, arrays, json

hello I want to go through my array and want to access the variables. But If I apply foreach it doesn't show anything. what I am doing wrong. Here is the array.

```
Array
(
    [22-2] => Array
        (
            [-L6mhtqkhmnyuMDkKkOX] => Array
                (
                    [receiver_id] => 2
                    [sender_id] => 22
                    [sender_name] => Rider One
                    [text] => i have done my all orders from post man 1
                    [timestamp] => 04-03-2018 21:00:42
                )
 [-L6miAxk59-jvAF2K_mA] => Array
                (
                    [receiver_id] => 2
                    [sender_id] => 22
                    [sender_name] => Rider One
                    [text] => Hahaha
                    [timestamp] => 05-03-2018 01:34:09
                )
```

This is what I am doing in the code.

```
$json_data = json_decode($response, true);

print("<pre>".print_r($json_data,true)."</pre>");

               foreach ($json_data as $key ) {

                    echo $key['22-2']['-L6mhtqkhmnyuMDkKkOX']['sender_name'].'<br>';

                }
```

It is not displaying the sender name. the only white blank page is showing

Comment: You don't need a `foreach()` for this, unless you want to print it twice.

Comment: I want to loop through the whole array and print sender name

Comment: iterate from  foreach ($json_data['22-2'] as $key )  and then access via $key['sender_name']

Comment: try this foreach ($json_data as $array) {
    foreach ($array as $data) {
        echo $data['sender_name'].'<br>';
    }
}